# Adobe Premiere Pro - How do I select a Region in the Timeline using Mouse

Tags: premiere

In Magix/Sony Vegas Pro I could just drag click it. I don't want to use the "in and out points" or how you call them, I want to select a region by drag-selecting with my mouse and then adjusting it if needed. I remember I did this somehow in Premiere Pro 2019 but I am not sure about this version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it can do exactly what you're asking for.

Nearest I can think of is selecting the razor blade tool (or press  <kbd>C</kbd>).
Making a cut using the mouse on your region, then switching back to the selection tool (or press <kbd>V</kbd>).
Then selecting your region, and adjusting the ends if necessary by floating over them, then dragging.

(In and Out points are massively useful when you get into more complex edits.  There's a reason most editing software uses them - they're worth learning to use).